# Compactly supported sections of a vector bundle form a cosheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, mathematical-physics, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am trying to understand why the compactly supported sections of a vector bundle form a cosheaf. I have proven that they form a precosheaf: simply extending the compactly supported section by zero proves this. However, checking the local to global property of a cosheaf I do not manage to prove. I found an argument only in Costello-Gwilliam: Factorization algebras in Quantum Field Theory, but I don't understand it. How can one use a partition of unity, to check the exactness of the following sequence:
\begin{equation*}
        \bigoplus_{(i, j)} F\left(U_i \cap U_j\right) \stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow} \bigoplus_i F\left(U_i\right) \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} F(U) \longrightarrow 0
    \end{equation*}
,where $F$ is the functor, which sends open sets to compactly supported sections of a vector bundle and $\alpha=\sum_{i \in I} \limits i_{U,U_i}$ and $\beta=\sum_{(i,j)} \limits(i_{U_i,U_i \cap U_j} -i_{U_j,U_i \cap U_j})$ and $i_{A,B}$ is the linear map coming from the inclusion $A\to B$ under the functor $F$,namely $i_{A,B}=F(A)\to F(B)$?

**EDIT:** To be more specific, my concrete confusion comes in how to prove $\text{im}(\beta)=\text{ker}(\alpha)$. Does one need partitions of unity for that? To show that alpha is surjective, which is part of the exactness, one does have to use a partition of unity, and as A.
Thomas Yerger noted, it follows more or less by definition.

Comment: Do you know what a partition of unity is? I think understanding the definition will show you why this works. (Please pardon my comment if it is ignorant. I thought about it, and it seems to me that partitions of unity exactly solve this problem, but if there's a subtlety, then it's entirely my misunderstanding).

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the notion of partition of unity, but I do not see how to use this notion to show exactness of the sequence. In particular, I have seen that for this problem we have to use partitions of unity *subordinate to the cover*, which have the extra property that the support lies entirely in the cover, i.e. $\text{supp} \rho_i \subseteq U_i$, where $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is the cover. I just don't see precisely how to use this.

Comment: Is $\beta$ defined correctly? Shouldn't it be sending a section on $U_i \cap U_j$ into $F(U_i) \oplus F(U_j)$ and $0$ elsewhere? Your expression is a difference of two things that doesn't make sense a priori. If you're missing a comma right in the middle, then I see the exactness and I will leave an answer.

Comment: I think $\beta$ is defined correctly. See for example page 281 of https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0647-7_6 . In their notation $\beta=g$, $\alpha=f$. But I used this notation, because in his 1968 original paper, he used $\beta,\alpha$.

Comment: How do I take the difference of these two things though if one lives in $F(U_i)$ and one lives in $F(U_j)$? I have Bredon's book. I can't access your link, but I can go get it off my shelf, let me go check it out.

Comment: Fair point. Maybe you take difference in $F(U_i) \oplus F(U_j)$, not in $F(U_i)$ neither in $F(U_j)$. The difference should be defined in $F(U_j) \oplus F(U_i)$. I am unsure actually. But I doubt the definiton itself would be mistaken in both the book and article. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I said then? You get two sections with opposite sign on the overlap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144355/discussion-between-prophetx-and-a-thomas-yerger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tentative answer under the assumption that $\beta$ is defined incorrectly, slightly. I think it should be as follows. Let $F$ be a vector bundle, and think of it as a functor taking values in vector spaces of sections. Then we have $\beta: \bigoplus_{i,j} F(U_i \cap U_j) \to \bigoplus_{i} F(U_i)$ and be defined by sending $$(\phi: U_i \cap U_j \to F) \mapsto \left( (i_*\phi:U_i \to F), (-i_*\phi:U_j \to F) \right)$$, where $i_*$ is the extension by $0$ of the inclusion, as in the question.

In this form, we consider the kernel of $\alpha$. This consists of all tuples of sections $\varphi_i: U_i \to F$ such that the $U_i$ sum to $0$ when you extend them all by $0$ to sections over all of $U$. For example, this happens when you have sections which are $0$ on the complement $U - \bigcup_{i,j} (U_i \cap U_j)$ and have opposite signs on the intersections, so that their sum is $0$. Well, this is exactly what $\beta$'s image is, by construction. We are sending things on the intersection to the same place with opposite sign so that they can be cancelled by $\alpha$.

Comment: I think this shows that $\text{im}(\beta) \subseteq \text{ker}(\alpha)$. What about the other way around?

Comment: I think it shows the reverse inclusion. I've characterized elements in the kernel of alpha, and proven that every element in that kernel is of the form of something in the image of beta.

Comment: After you characterised elements of the kernel, you wrote 'For example'. I agree with that. How do we show that these exhaust all the possibilities, i.e. there is no other case, when the $\varphi_i$-s sum up to zero?

Comment: I guess that's a poor choice of words. i'm pretty sure the last bit is just a little bit of algebra.